# How to manage transient data in a Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React/Redux application that requires me to manage temporary data in the application's state.

The user performs a client side Edit or Remove operation on the business data.
He then goes on to work on the App with the updated(temporary) data.
If satisfied with the edit/remove operation, user can then decide to 'SAVE' his action. This would commit changes to the backend server via an ajax call.

If not satisfied, user can choose to 'REVERT' the operation. This should bring the application data back to it's original state prior to Edit/Remove operation.

I'm required to manage the transient/temporary data till the user decides either to Save or Revert the changes made.

I've considered the option of maintaining the temporary data seperate from it's orginal structure. If successfully commited to server,
then update the origin from the API response and clear off the temporary data.
If action is reverted, the original data remains same and the temporary is cleared.

What would be a good approach to managing temporary Redux states such as this that can either go on to persist or be discarded..?